# How to connect an local VM to an local MariaDB docker

Tags: docker, mariadb, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I'm trying to connect an local VM (with debian) to a local running docker with MariaDB.

Creation of docker:
`docker run --name my_mariadb_host -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -d mariadb`

I've check the output of `ifconfig` for docker and this is the result:

> docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>
> inet 192.168.50.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.50.255
>
> ether 02:42:b3:f1:96:85  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>
> RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>
> TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

so the IP that I have to use is `192.168.50.1`

Also, if I'm running `ping 192.168.50.1` from VM or localhost in both cases it works and I am getting this result:

> PING 192.168.50.1 (192.168.50.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
>
> 64 bytes from 192.168.50.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.125 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 192.168.50.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.223 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 192.168.50.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms

Also my docker mariadb is on a host network as it can be seen via `docker inspect host`:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "host",
        "Id": "76a492635c0136dec012069bccd56ebfca8e7b3edcb556f1cbb2ccf0c95bfd70",
        "Created": "2022-09-14T15:14:34.484144209+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "host",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": []
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "3b7cf8fb12fd4cfe6452f982382102536fcc2a75817c1429698f73c2e0a2046e": {
                "Name": "my_mariadb_host",
                "EndpointID": "a50fa022569e8bfbca26ff3bb45b93052873580ab19aeaf36fd395e857071eea",
                "MacAddress": "",
                "IPv4Address": "",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

If I'm running this command `mysql -h 192.168.50.1 -P 3306 --protocol=TCP -u root -p` inside of my localhost (my PC) everything works and I can connect successfuly to docker MySQL.

But if I'm running the same command on by VM, is going to get stuck right after I will put my password.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The container should appear to the VM like any other process directly running on the host.  You don't need to look up the `docker0` IP address and I wouldn't try to use it here.  If you were running MySQL directly on the host, how would you connect to it from the VM, and can you use that exact same setup with MySQL in a container on the host with a published port?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but I don't run the docker inside of my VM in order to appear as a regular process, that's the whole problem. I am running a docker container inside my computer and also a VM inside of my computer, the problem is that the HOST can communicate with the Docker but the VM cant.

Comment: also as I said I can ping the ip from both VM and HOST, shouldn't be it enough?

Comment: MySQL doesn't accept the very-low-level ICMP packets that ping(1) sends.  Ignoring all of the diagnostics, my base expectation is that the database should appear to the VM exactly like a MySQL database running on the host system outside a container.

Comment: and if so, how can I check it? because so far I've checked, I don't have MySQL installed on my VM, because it is inside the docker container and I should access it remotely. That's my problem.

Comment: What does your VM think the IP address of the host is?  Connect to that, ignore anything Docker-related.  Installing the `mysql` CLI tool inside the VM could be helpful here.

Comment: I can't do that because of some constraints, but should not really matter, or at leat I think it does not, because my docker is in a host network, which means is the same as my HOST. So if this is the case, shouldn't I be able to connect it? More than that, the MySQL should be able to connect via a remote source. So ai am still not sure what I am doing wrong, but it should be able to connect...

Comment: also my VM is seeing the IP of the docker with mysql, otherwise I would be able to ping it, or am I wrong?

Comment: Your container is using the default bridge network, but since you've published a port you can access it using the host's IP address.  Ignore all Docker-related IP addresses as internal details.

Comment: no... my container is using the host network as you can see in my description above... and also as I said... I cant access it from VM I can access it just from my host.

Comment: look into the description after `docker inspect host`, as you can see that's my container,                 `"Name": "my_mariadb_host",` and is using the host network.